# symfony2 doctrine FormType - populate choice field with values from another entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations, entity

I have a system with three entities: User, Author and Topic.
Topic {id}<---> Author{topic_id,user_id} <---> User {id,name}

Enitity/Author.php

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="Authors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Topic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="topic_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $topic_id;
```

Entity/Topic.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="my\myBundle\Repository\TopicRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="topic")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Topic
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->author = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setStartDate(new \DateTime());
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $state = '0';
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
     */
    protected $subject;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=300, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $comment;
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Author", mappedBy="topic_id")
    */
    protected $authors;
```

Entity/User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="my\myBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="user_id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $id;
```

so as you see there is an association path like this

Topic <---> Author <---> User

Now i have a form to add new Topic. I want to display there a choice field where it would be populated with names from USER table.
I do this in this way:

```
class TopicType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('subject')
            ->add('authors', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p'); },
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                ));
    }
```

This does indeed populate the field with correct values. However, when i submit the form i get an error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ...\Entity\Topic::setAuthors() must be an instance of ...\Entity\User,
>   instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called
>   in
>   /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php
>   on line 538 and defined in .../Entity/Topic.php line 192

And I do understand that Im passing incorrect argument but i dont know how to fix this.
I need the doctrine to take user names from entity User, put the into the field, correlate ids with the names and once i submit the form it must refer to the method Topic.addAuthors($ids).

Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `$autors` property setter that is defined like

```
public function setAuthors(User $author) ...
```

But you have OneToMany relationship on your property and `multiple = true` at your form field, so setter must be defined like:

```
public function setAuthors($authors) ...
```

Comment: Well i did the change as suggested abd the error message is now different:
Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association my\myBundle\Entity\Topic#authors, but expecting my\myBundle\Entity\Author
Any ideas..?

Comment: Author.php http://pastebin.com/AewW1sBF
Topic.php http://pastebin.com/5KwTuUxq
User.php http://pastebin.com/ERvVD6FC